# Why is the height of my div element not working correctly in my case?

Tags: html, css

I specified the layout of my document using percentage values. However, I'm unable to understand the behavior of my CSS. What I think I'm doing is:

1. Telling the height of the `HTML` element to always be 100vh.
2. Telling the height of the `body` element to be 100% of the html (so 100vh).
3. Telling my containers to be a percentage of the height of the body (so, 20%, 60%, 20%).

So, in a viewport of 1000px. My html and body elements height will be 1000px.
My other containers will have a height of 200px, 600px, and 200px. With the 600px container (.songs-container) having a scroll bar when it's contents overflows.

However, this is not the behaviour I see. Because of something I don't understand, my .`songs-container` overflows the height of the body and no scroll bar shows up.

Why is my `.songs-container` not adhering to the percentage height that I have specified for it and how do I fix it?

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}

body {
  background: #41403e;
  height: 100%;
}

.songs-container {
  height: 60%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.song {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--primary);
}

.current-song {
  background: var(--danger-light-10);
}

.search-container {
  max-height: 20%;
}

.controls-container {
  max-height: 20%;
}

.submit-btn--half-block {
  width: 50%;
}

.input-container--block {
  width: 100%;
}

@media(min-width: 600px) {
  .main {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/papercss@1.9.2/dist/paper.min.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="main" data-controller="songs">
      <turbo-frame id="search-and-songs">
        <form class="search-container row" action="http://localhost:3000/songs" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
          <div class="form-group input-container--block">
            <input class="input-block" placeholder="Search" type="text" name="song_title" id="song_title" />
          </div>
          <div class='row input-container--block'>
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="search" class="submit-btn--half-block" data-disable-with="search" />
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="clear" class="submit-btn--half-block" data-disable-with="clear" />
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class='songs-container child-shadows child-shadows-hover'>
          <a id="song_210" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Rachana Dahal  Bhumari Official Lyric Video.mp3" data-id="210">Rachana Dahal Bhumari Official Lyric Video.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_211" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/The Beatles - Penny Lane.mp3" data-id="211">The Beatles - Penny Lane.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_212" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/The Psychology of Self-Transformation.mp3" data-id="212">The Psychology of Self-Transformation.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_213" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Arthur Gunn - Have you ever seen the rain (Creedence Clearwater Revival).mp3" data-id="213">Arthur Gunn - Have you ever seen the rain (Creedence Clearwater Revival).mp3</a>
          <a id="song_214" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Khaabon Ke Parinday (Full video song) Zindagi Na Milegi Dobara Hrithik Roshan, Kartina Kaif.mp3" data-id="214">Khaabon Ke Parinday (Full video song) Zindagi Na Milegi Dobara Hrithik Roshan, Kartina Kaif.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_215" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Extreme - More Than Words (Lyrics Video).mp3" data-id="215">Extreme - More Than Words (Lyrics Video).mp3</a>
          <a id="song_216" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Pichle saat Dinon Mein - Rock On!! - OST.mp3" data-id="216">Pichle saat Dinon Mein - Rock On!! - OST.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_217" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Bipul Chettri  Syndicate Single.mp3" data-id="217">Bipul Chettri Syndicate Single.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_218" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Why Shakespeare Because its 2016  Stephen Brown  TEDxStMaryCSSchool.mp3" data-id="218">Why Shakespeare Because its 2016 Stephen Brown TEDxStMaryCSSchool.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_219" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Senator Bernie Sanders Full Address Oxford Union.mp3" data-id="219">Senator Bernie Sanders Full Address Oxford Union.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_220" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Kalo Keshma Relimai - Dinesh Dhakal | Lyrical Video.mp3" data-id="220">Kalo Keshma Relimai - Dinesh Dhakal | Lyrical Video.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_221" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/A.R. Rahman - Luka Chuppi Best Audio SongRang De BasantiAamir KhanLata MangeshkarSoha.mp3" data-id="221">A.R. Rahman - Luka Chuppi Best Audio SongRang De BasantiAamir KhanLata MangeshkarSoha.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_222" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Nabin K Bhattarai Timi Hau Lakhau Ko Dhadkan Nepali Pop Song.mp3" data-id="222">Nabin K Bhattarai Timi Hau Lakhau Ko Dhadkan Nepali Pop Song.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_223" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/The Beatles - While My Guitar Gently Weeps.mp3" data-id="223">The Beatles - While My Guitar Gently Weeps.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_224" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Aakhama Timilai Nabin K Bhattarai Raharai Raharma   .mp3" data-id="224">Aakhama Timilai Nabin K Bhattarai Raharai Raharma .mp3</a>
          <a id="song_225" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Kadam  Prateek Kuhad  Lyrics.mp3" data-id="225">Kadam Prateek Kuhad Lyrics.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_226" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Ricky Gervais Out Of England 2 - The Stand Up Special (Full show in 720p with English captions) (128 kbps)(1).mp3" data-id="226">Ricky Gervais Out Of England 2 - The Stand Up Special (Full show in 720p with English captions) (128 kbps)(1).mp3</a>
          <a id="song_227" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Eagles - Hotel California.mp3" data-id="227">Eagles - Hotel California.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_228" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Nepathya  Sirfula Siraima  .mp3" data-id="228">Nepathya Sirfula Siraima .mp3</a>
          <a id="song_229" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Kun Faya Kun Full Video Song RockstarRanbir kapoor.mp3" data-id="229">Kun Faya Kun Full Video Song RockstarRanbir kapoor.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_230" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/The Long And Winding Road -The Beatles.mp3" data-id="230">The Long And Winding Road -The Beatles.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_231" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/George Carlin on Fat People.mp3" data-id="231">George Carlin on Fat People.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_232" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Iron and Wine - Boy With A Coin.mp3" data-id="232">Iron and Wine - Boy With A Coin.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_233" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Kabira Full Song Yeh Jawaani Hai Deewani  Ranbir Kapoor Deepika Padukone.mp3" data-id="233">Kabira Full Song Yeh Jawaani Hai Deewani Ranbir Kapoor Deepika Padukone.mp3</a>
          <a id="song_234" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/la vie en rose - edith piaf (cover).mp3" data-id="234">la vie en rose - edith piaf (cover).mp3</a>
          <a id="song_235" class="song padding-small" data-action="click-&gt;songs#play" data-href="songs/Kanchhi Hey Kanchhi  Kanchhi  Old Nepali Movie Song.mp3" data-id="235">Kanchhi Hey Kanchhi Kanchhi Old Nepali Movie Song.mp3</a>
        </div>
      </turbo-frame>
      <div class="controls-container padding-small">
        <div id="audio-container" data-songs-target="audioContainer">
          <audio data-controller="mediaplayer" controls src=""></audio>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="paper-btn btn-small" data-action="click->songs#prev">Prev</button>
          <button class="paper-btn btn-small" data-action="click->songs#next">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

  </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Add `overflow` rule. Now your text expands your elements.

Comment: Provide your html code

Comment: I just added a fiddle with my whole code.
https://jsfiddle.net/aviii/1L6gtvun/3/

Comment: Next time add the code in as a snippet. There is no point using external resources to share your code

Comment: Sure. Thanks for editing it btw

Comment: try to use `main{height:100%}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage heights always works relative to the parent. So if you miss percentage height for any one of the parent, the child element cant have a percentage height.

As per your DOM structure, you should have the below split-up for the heights.

[image]

You missed these definitions in your css.

```
main {
  height: 100%;
}

#search-and-songs {
  height: 80%;
  display: block;
}
```

So the below code should be the way that you should implement this.

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}

body {
  background: #41403e;
  height: 100%;
}

.songs-container {
  height: 80%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.song {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: lightblue;
}

.current-song {
  background: pink;
}

.search-container {
  max-height: 20%;
}

.controls-container {
  height: 20%;
}

.submit-btn--half-block {
  width: 50%;
}

.input-container--block {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .main {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

main {
  height: 100%;
}

#search-and-songs {
  height: 80%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/papercss@1.9.2/dist/paper.min.css"
/>
<main class="main" data-controller="songs">
  <turbo-frame id="search-and-songs">
    <form
      class="search-container row"
      action="http://localhost:3000/songs"
      accept-charset="UTF-8"
      method="get"
    >
      <div class="form-group input-container--block">
        <input
          class="input-block"
          placeholder="Search"
          type="text"
          name="song_title"
          id="song_title"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="row input-container--block">
        <input
          type="submit"
          name="commit"
          value="search"
          class="submit-btn--half-block"
          data-disable-with="search"
        />
        <input
          type="submit"
          name="commit"
          value="clear"
          class="submit-btn--half-block"
          data-disable-with="clear"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="songs-container child-shadows child-shadows-hover">
      <a
        id="song_210"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Rachana Dahal  Bhumari Official Lyric Video.mp3"
        data-id="210"
        >Rachana Dahal Bhumari Official Lyric Video.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_211"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/The Beatles - Penny Lane.mp3"
        data-id="211"
        >The Beatles - Penny Lane.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_212"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/The Psychology of Self-Transformation.mp3"
        data-id="212"
        >The Psychology of Self-Transformation.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_213"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Arthur Gunn - Have you ever seen the rain (Creedence Clearwater Revival).mp3"
        data-id="213"
        >Arthur Gunn - Have you ever seen the rain (Creedence Clearwater
        Revival).mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_214"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Khaabon Ke Parinday (Full video song) Zindagi Na Milegi Dobara Hrithik Roshan, Kartina Kaif.mp3"
        data-id="214"
        >Khaabon Ke Parinday (Full video song) Zindagi Na Milegi Dobara
        Hrithik Roshan, Kartina Kaif.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_215"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Extreme - More Than Words (Lyrics Video).mp3"
        data-id="215"
        >Extreme - More Than Words (Lyrics Video).mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_216"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Pichle saat Dinon Mein - Rock On!! - OST.mp3"
        data-id="216"
        >Pichle saat Dinon Mein - Rock On!! - OST.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_217"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Bipul Chettri  Syndicate Single.mp3"
        data-id="217"
        >Bipul Chettri Syndicate Single.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_218"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Why Shakespeare Because its 2016  Stephen Brown  TEDxStMaryCSSchool.mp3"
        data-id="218"
        >Why Shakespeare Because its 2016 Stephen Brown
        TEDxStMaryCSSchool.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_219"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Senator Bernie Sanders Full Address Oxford Union.mp3"
        data-id="219"
        >Senator Bernie Sanders Full Address Oxford Union.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_220"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Kalo Keshma Relimai - Dinesh Dhakal | Lyrical Video.mp3"
        data-id="220"
        >Kalo Keshma Relimai - Dinesh Dhakal | Lyrical Video.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_221"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/A.R. Rahman - Luka Chuppi Best Audio SongRang De BasantiAamir KhanLata MangeshkarSoha.mp3"
        data-id="221"
        >A.R. Rahman - Luka Chuppi Best Audio SongRang De BasantiAamir
        KhanLata MangeshkarSoha.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_222"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Nabin K Bhattarai Timi Hau Lakhau Ko Dhadkan Nepali Pop Song.mp3"
        data-id="222"
        >Nabin K Bhattarai Timi Hau Lakhau Ko Dhadkan Nepali Pop Song.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_223"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/The Beatles - While My Guitar Gently Weeps.mp3"
        data-id="223"
        >The Beatles - While My Guitar Gently Weeps.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_224"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Aakhama Timilai Nabin K Bhattarai Raharai Raharma   .mp3"
        data-id="224"
        >Aakhama Timilai Nabin K Bhattarai Raharai Raharma .mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_225"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Kadam  Prateek Kuhad  Lyrics.mp3"
        data-id="225"
        >Kadam Prateek Kuhad Lyrics.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_226"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Ricky Gervais Out Of England 2 - The Stand Up Special (Full show in 720p with English captions) (128 kbps)(1).mp3"
        data-id="226"
        >Ricky Gervais Out Of England 2 - The Stand Up Special (Full show in
        720p with English captions) (128 kbps)(1).mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_227"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Eagles - Hotel California.mp3"
        data-id="227"
        >Eagles - Hotel California.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_228"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Nepathya  Sirfula Siraima  .mp3"
        data-id="228"
        >Nepathya Sirfula Siraima .mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_229"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Kun Faya Kun Full Video Song RockstarRanbir kapoor.mp3"
        data-id="229"
        >Kun Faya Kun Full Video Song RockstarRanbir kapoor.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_230"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/The Long And Winding Road -The Beatles.mp3"
        data-id="230"
        >The Long And Winding Road -The Beatles.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_231"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/George Carlin on Fat People.mp3"
        data-id="231"
        >George Carlin on Fat People.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_232"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Iron and Wine - Boy With A Coin.mp3"
        data-id="232"
        >Iron and Wine - Boy With A Coin.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_233"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Kabira Full Song Yeh Jawaani Hai Deewani  Ranbir Kapoor Deepika Padukone.mp3"
        data-id="233"
        >Kabira Full Song Yeh Jawaani Hai Deewani Ranbir Kapoor Deepika
        Padukone.mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_234"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/la vie en rose - edith piaf (cover).mp3"
        data-id="234"
        >la vie en rose - edith piaf (cover).mp3</a
      >
      <a
        id="song_235"
        class="song padding-small"
        data-action="click-&gt;songs#play"
        data-href="songs/Kanchhi Hey Kanchhi  Kanchhi  Old Nepali Movie Song.mp3"
        data-id="235"
        >Kanchhi Hey Kanchhi Kanchhi Old Nepali Movie Song.mp3</a
      >
    </div>
  </turbo-frame>
  <div class="controls-container padding-small">
    <div id="audio-container" data-songs-target="audioContainer">
      <audio data-controller="mediaplayer" controls src=""></audio>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="paper-btn btn-small" data-action="click->songs#prev">
        Prev
      </button>
      <button class="paper-btn btn-small" data-action="click->songs#next">
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```